# Checkbox show/hide changes not displaying on angular page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When user clicks on the checkbox, I want to hide some contents.

Below is my code,

```
<input id="IsBlock" class="e-field e-input" type="checkbox" name="IsBlock" style="width: 100%" #check>
```

And to hide based on checkbox checked

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!check.checked">
```

Above code works only if I perform some mouse action like clicking on page.

Please help.

Comment: If you have written like this "<ng-container *ngIf="!check.checked">"
I believe you are missing closing tag for ng-container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular only updates bindings if there are some changes in the state of the app so you need to bind some action to the checkbox. By simply adding

```
(change)="true"
```

to your checkbox will solve your problem.